# Solidity events in libraries - not displaying correctly in Mist

Tags: solidity, mist, library

Has anybody been successful in executing and viewing events (in Mist) generated from solidity libraries?

My contract can log and display events in the contract but events in the associated libraries are not being displayed correctly in Mist.

I am not sure if this is a solidity issue, node client issue (using Geth) or a Mist issue.

Screenshot attached of library event in Mist.

Added issue to Github - https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1083

[image]

Comment: Hello from 5 1/2 years in the future. It's definitely not just a Mist thing because I can see events not displaying properly on the online blockchain scanners.

Answer (score 3):

Found a workaround for this bug. All library events have to be duplicated in the calling contract for the events to log correctly.

Comment: So you just copy and paste the definition of the event that you want in the library inside the contract and it works ?